# react native access title of the current screen in nested drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-navigation-drawer

I have a react native app using react-navigation where i want my header to look like this with a title and subtitle.

[image]

I'm using native-base Header to achieve this. At the root of the application i have a tabs navigation and each tab has a drawer navigation of its own. Like below 
[image]

For all the tabs there is separate Header component inside which the Title i have hard coded. The sub title is supposed to be the title of the current active screen similar to the `drawerLabel` or the `title` which are configured in the navigation options. But i'm not able to access the same in my header component. I even pass the `navigation` as a prop to the header but it contains the tab as the active route and not the initialRoute of the drawer as active route. This is how i use the header component

```
 <MyHeader navigation={navigation} subTitle={''} openDrawer={this.openDrawer}></MyHeader >
```

Below is my Drawer config

```
const DrawerConfig = {
   Screen1: {
      screen: Screen1,
      path: 'screen1',
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
         title: `Screen 1`,
         drawerLabel: 'Screen 1',
      }),
   }, Screen2: {
      screen: Screen2,
      path: 'screen2',
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
         title: `Screen 2`,
         drawerLabel: 'Screen 2'
      }),
   }
}
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(DrawerConfig, {
   initialRouteName: 'Screen1',
   contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent,
});
const MyDrawerNavigator = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
export default MyDrawerNavigator;
```

I have event tried creating stack for each of the screen and have the default header but i was not able to customize it by passing in a custom header component which the docs say should work.

```
 const MyScreen1Stack = createStackNavigator(
    {
       Screen1: {
          screen: Screen1,
       }
    },
    {
       navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          initialRouteName: 'Screen1',
          title: 'Screen 1',
          drawerLabel: 'Screen 1',
          header: ()=> <MyHeader />,
          heaMode: 'screen'
       }),
    },
 );
```

Below are the dependencies i have

```
"native-base": "^2.13.8",
"react": "16.8.1",
"react-native": "0.61.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
"react-native-modal": "^11.4.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~1.2.0",
"react-native-screens": "1.0.0-alpha.23",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.1",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.2",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6"
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const MyScreen1Stack = createStackNavigator(
{
   Screen1: {
      screen: Screen1,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header:<CustomHeader navigation={navigation}/>
      });
   }
});
```

Using custom header to this way and pass navigation props to header so you can access navigation in custom header and you can pass title and subtitle as a props as well.

```
<CustomHeader title="this is title" subtitle="this is subtitle"/>
```